# Heroku: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I have a java project with spring boot and spring security that I deployed to Heroku, but when I tried to access a simple endpoint to test, typing the url in chrome address bar, I received  ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

URL  I tried to access:

> https://myapp.herokuapp.com/public/ping-pong/ping/ping

endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/public/ping-pong")
public class PingPongController
{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ping/{ping}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> ping(@PathVariable("ping") final String ping)
    {
        try
        {
            String resp = "What?";
            if (ping.equals("ping"))
            {
                resp = "pong";
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(resp, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

}
```

Log:

```
2018-11-18T18:52:29.115442+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/public/ping-pong/ping/ping" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=a3eaab69-a559-4bae-b32c-7024f7d
5be55 fwd="179.234.39.93" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=302 bytes=166 protocol=https
2018-11-18T18:52:29.293482+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/public/ping-pong/ping/ping" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=a5fe02fc-8efc-41d0-a0f0-c54143d
5fa5e fwd="179.234.39.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=302 bytes=166 protocol=https
2018-11-18T18:52:29.472844+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/public/ping-pong/ping/ping" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=9f2dcf7b-1e5c-4038-ba4b-736d4f8
8f660 fwd="179.234.39.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=166 protocol=https
2018-11-18T18:52:29.646112+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/public/ping-pong/ping/ping" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=4c8206d7-09b4-43d3-922e-cd84502
ce198 fwd="179.234.39.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=166 protocol=https
2018-11-18T18:52:29.818152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/public/ping-pong/ping/ping" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=8f3efc04-8402-4377-8ed3-8732271
d13b9 fwd="179.234.39.93" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=302 bytes=166 protocol=https
```

This endpoint is working very well locally, so I think the problem could be some configuration on Heroku.

Can anyone help me?